# High level discussion: anomaly monitor

Tags: transactions, security, accounts, contract-invocation

I was reading about past attacks on Ethereum network and I pictured the following hypothetical scenario: there is a tool or automated, machine learning based anomalous monitor to check out constantly account's behavior, considering some factors such as account's level of activity, gas spent/received and so on.

Given this scenario, I would like to post the following question: who would benefit at most of being aware of what could be considered anomalous activity accounts? Who would be interested to know about any report generated by this hypothetic monitor?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing account activity is a part of the blockchain as a public ledger. People can (and do) monitor various accounts for their own reasons; larger accounts are generally monitored more than lesser ones.

To answer your question, everyone can be aware of every transaction if they try hard enough. The only benefit to this would be if the stalker had some sort of malware set up on the computer of the account holder so that the malicious entity could send himself Ether from the compromised address. [This does happen from time to time.](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5e4pn2/ive_been_robbed/) Other than that, large contracts or accounts are often viewed by people to see various stats and holdings (ie DAO contract, top hodlers, etc.)

Comment: nice comment and interesting what you pointed out. How about if traders had this information and could anticipate certain actions based on that? If, for example, some crypto media had the access to this source of information and could be the 1st to break the story?  Or even, Ethereum developers could have access and then begin to work on any necessary fix?